# How can I define a variable in an Angular template using ngIf, but with a type?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, intellij-idea, ionic4

I've abstracted this out into a more generic Angular use case. We do have some issues with ngIf, but mostly it's Ionic's virtualItem.

See image below. territoryCode and createDate aren't found by IntelliJ. I don't know how to define the type after "let ticketGroup" or "let ticket".

- "as" does not work.

```
Property virtualItemAs is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template.
```

- ":" does not work. Syntax error.

[image]

[image]

Edit: This is what happens when I do async as item for virtualItem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for asynchronous data, the object can be undefined. In this case, you can use ngIf and store the result of the condition in a local variable as shown in the the following example

```
*ngIf="details$ | async as ticket"
```

Comment: any idea what the virtualItem syntax would be? I tried the async thing. Added a screenshot to the description so you can see what it says

Comment: For using virtualItem you must to have <ion-list [virtualScroll]=“someData”>

Comment: Then just define *virtualItem=“let item”

Answer (score 0):

These are IDE bugs; please follow [WEB-43715](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43715) and [WEB-43716](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43716) for updates